# The effect of the value of capacitance in relation to the load resistance of a single capacitor in smoothing

Tags: capacitance

I can't find a good explanation about:

> The effect of the value of capacitance in relation to the load resistance of a single capacitor in smoothing.

I think it has to do with the following formula:

> $R_{load}   *   C   >>   1   /   f$

Where:
$R_{load}$ = the overall resistance of the load for the supply

C = value of capacitor in Farads

f = the ripple frequency (the time between two peaks [in the same direction])

Which is (I think) stating that the capacitor has to discharge fully in a time that is shorter than the time for half of the period of the sinusoidal wave that represents the current.

Is my thinking correct?

*(I am doing high school level physics so I don't have very advanced knowledge.)*

Comment: google for low-pass filter for more information or check [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Electronic_low-pass_filters)